# Using a lazy var and Xcode still says cannot use instance, property initializers run before 'self'?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a `text` box that changes to a random one from a `list` when a `button` is pressed.
All im really trying to change I the `background` `color`, but then I decided I wanted a `gradient` instead. It was working fine when I only had `colors` in the `backgrounds` `list`, but now when I try to make a `gradient` `var`, so I don't have to put each `gradient` in the `list`, I keep getting the same `error`. 
Ive tried doing this all kinds of different ways and can't seem to get it to work anyway I try it. I feel like there has to be a way though.

```
    import SwiftUI




struct ContentView: View {

    lazy var drinkGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("drinkcard1"), Color("drinkcard2")]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)]
    lazy var truthGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("truthcard"), Color("truthcard")]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)]
    lazy var dareGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("darecard"), Color("darecard")]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)]

    @State private var backgrounds = [truthGradient[0], dareGradient[0], truthGradient[0], dareGradient[0], truthGradient[0], dareGradient[0], drinkGradient[0]]
    @State private var text = [String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Drink!!")]
    @State private var foregrounds = [Color.black, Color.white]
    @State private var number = [0]



    var body: some View {

        ZStack{

            //Background
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color("background"))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            //All content
            VStack {

                //Banner
                HStack {

                    Text("Truth, Dare or Drink")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.bottom, 30)
                        .padding(.top, 80)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)



                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth:  .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .background(Color("banner"))
                .shadow(radius: 20)
                Spacer()

                Text(text[number[0]])
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(foregrounds[0])
                .padding(.all, 75)
                .background(backgrounds[number[0]])
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding(.all)

                Button(action: {
                    self.number[0] = Int.random(in:
                        0...self.text.count - 1)

                    if self.number[0] == 0{

                    }

                }) {
                    Text("Spin")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(.vertical, 15)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 80)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(Color("button"))
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                        .shadow(radius: 15)
                        .padding(.all)

                }
                Spacer()


            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)



        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `drinkGradient`, `truthGradient` and `dareGradient` essentially constants, or will they change dynamically, and you want `backgrounds` to change with them?

Comment: add code which we can copy and paste and see your error. The snippet you gave us is useless....

Comment: @chris I added the rest of the code

Comment: @sweeper I have a button that randomly chooses a number between 0 and the length of the lists -1 and the `text` is set to `number` so I want the certain attributes such as `text`, `background color` (aka the gradient), and im going to have my `foreground` color change based on what the random number is. but the `text` has to line up with the correct `gradient`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution could be to do the variables in a class like so:

```
 class Colors {
    static var drinkGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("drinkcard1"), Color("drinkcard2")]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)]
    static var truthGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("truthcard"), Color("truthcard")]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)]
    static var dareGradient = [LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("darecard"), Color("darecard")]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)]
 }

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var backgrounds = [Colors.truthGradient[0], Colors.dareGradient[0], Colors.truthGradient[0], Colors.dareGradient[0], Colors.truthGradient[0], Colors.dareGradient[0], Colors.drinkGradient[0]]
    @State private var text = [String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Truth"), String("Dare"), String("Drink!!")]
    @State private var foregrounds = [Color.black, Color.white]
    @State private var number = [0]

    var body: some View {

        ZStack{

            //Background
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color("background"))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            //All content
            VStack {

                //Banner
                HStack {

                    Text("Truth, Dare or Drink")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.bottom, 30)
                        .padding(.top, 80)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)



                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth:  .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .background(Color("banner"))
                .shadow(radius: 20)
                Spacer()

                Text(text[0])
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(foregrounds[0])
                .padding(.all, 75)
                .background(backgrounds[0])
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding(.all)

                Button(action: {
                    self.number[0] = Int.random(in:
                        0...self.text.count - 1)

                    if self.number[0] == 0{

                    }

                }) {
                    Text("Spin")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(.vertical, 15)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 80)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(Color("button"))
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                        .shadow(radius: 15)
                        .padding(.all)

                }
                Spacer()


            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)



        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it all. I just started learning swift last night and am still trying to get used to it. Thank you for the help.